# C program - causes crash with Pointer

Tags: c, pointers

in this C program when i am using

```
printf("%c",*(name+5));
```

then program works fine but when i am using

```
*(name+5) = '#';
```

then program causes crash

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(void)
{
    char * name;
    name ="Hello World !";
    puts(name);
    *(name+5) = '#'; // here is error 
    puts(name);
}
```

Comment: C or C++ program?

Answer (score 3):

With...

```
char * name;
name ="Hello World !";
*(name+5) = '#';
```

you are manipulating the contents of a string literal, which is undefined behaviour, likely a crash.

Make an array out of it, which you may alter then:

```
char name[] ="Hello World !";
name[5] = '#';
```

or:

```
char buffer[] ="Hello World !";
char *name = buffer;
*(name+5) = '#';
```

Note that here the contents of string literal `"Hello World!"` are copied into an array which's content you are allowed to change.